# NullPointerException at the TextView.setText()

Tags: android, listview, dialog, textview

My textView is on my DialogBox.
I have a listView of all list, when i click an item on the list, a dialog will pop up with a textview. but everytime a click a null pointer exception will come out. on the textViewReason.setText(transferPurpose);

```
if(status.equals("Disapproved"))
                 {
                    TextView textViewReason = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewReasonDenied);                         
                    textViewReason.setText(transferPurpose);
                     Dialog formDialog = onCreateDialog(1);    

                     //((TextView)formDialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewReasonDenied)).setText(transferPurpose);

                     formDialog.show();
                 }
```

Comment: where is textViewReasonDenied  declared?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(status.equals("Disapproved"))
{
  Dialog formDialog = onCreateDialog(1);   
  TextView textViewReason = (TextView)formDialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewReasonDenied);                         
  textViewReason.setText(transferPurpose);          
  formDialog.show();
 }
```

also check if yout transferPurpose String is not a null : )

Answer (score 0):

"R.id.textViewReasonDenied" must be a component of type TextView, it is in the main.xml or activity_main layout.
Good luck,